# VBA: Autofilter method of Range Class Failed

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting the error

> Autofilter method of range class failed

on the line

`RngToSearch.AutoFilter 1, Criteria1:=ProgramNoVal`

What I am trying to do is filter the data in column C of the Program Main sheet based on `ProgramNoVal` and then copy the value for the corresponding column K in my Mkting tab at `RngDest`.

```
Sub test()

Dim ProgramNoVal
Dim RngToSearch As Range, Rng As Range, RngDest As Range
ProgramNoVal = Sheets("Instructions").Range("G12").Value

With Sheets("Mkting")
        Set RngDest = .Range("D1")
End With

Sheets("ProgramMain").Select
Set RngToSearch = Range("C1:K30000")
Set Rng = RngToSearch.Offset(1, 8).Resize(RngToSearch.Rows.Count - 1, 1)

ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
RngToSearch.AutoFilter 1, Criteria1:=ProgramNoVal
Rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy RngDest
RngToSearch.AutoFilter

End Sub
```

I have tried this a different way, using vlookup. I get a type mismatch for foundRow. The value it is finding is a string. I have tried string, long, range, etc and nothing works. Solutions to either of these pieces of code is appreciated. The code for vlookup is:

```
Sub test()

Dim ProgramNoVal
Dim RngToSearch As Range, Rng As Range, RngDest As Range
Dim foundRow As long


With Sheets("Mkting")
   Set RngDest = .Range("D1")
End With

ProgramNoVal = Sheets("Instructions").Range("G12").Value

    Set RngToSearch = Sheets("ProgramMain").Range("C1:K30000")
    foundRow = Sheets("ProgramMain").Application.VLookup(ProgramNoVal, RngToSearch, 9, False)

    If Not IsError(foundRow) Then
        RngToSearch.Cells(foundRow, 1).Copy RngDest
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What value is in `Sheets("Instructions").Range("G12").Value`? That autofilter will fail for instance if G12 contains an error value.

Comment: It doesn't. It has a 4 digit number that identifies the program we work with. I then want to find data for that same program in the ProgramMain spreadsheet.

Comment: David, I tried to adapt the vlookup code you gave me yesterday but get a type mismatch problem - see above. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: which line gives the error?

Comment: For the typemismatch its the row: foundRow = Sheets("ProgramMain").Application.VLookup(ProgramNoVal, RngToSearch, 9, False)

Comment: OK. See below for full explanation. I revised my answer to your other Q, I had mistakenly declared `foundRow` as Long when it should have been `As Variant`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Dim foundRow as Variant`.

This is because, if the value can't be found/doesn't exist, then `Application.Vlookup` will return an error type, which will raise a mismatch when assigned to a Long type variable.

But since vlookup returns the *value* and not the position of the cell, we can't use that the way we were trying to (which is what I get for not testing my code).

Instead of `VLOOKUP` use `MATCH`:

```
foundRow = Sheets("ProgramMain").Application.Match(ProgramNoVal, RngToSearch.Columns(1), False)
```

The `Match` function returns the relative row position of the searched for value. Since we're searching a range that begins in row 1, we can use this value without any modifications:

```
If Not IsError(foundRow) Then
    RngToSearch.Cells(foundRow, 1).Copy RngDest
End If
```

Comment: Hi, that works - thank you! But now I am getting the type mismatch on this line of code "RngToSearch.Cells(foundRow, 1).Copy RngDest". Not sure what is causing that. Both Rngtosearch and RngDest are set as Range

Comment: what have you done to debug this? If asking a Q here is your first recourse, please reconsider. What is the *value* of `foundRow` at the time this error is raised?

Comment: I have tried many things - because setting foundRow as a variant worked, and RngToSearch has to be a range because it is looking at C1:K3000, I assume the problem is in the type of RngDest? I have tried RngDest is to everything I can think of (the end value is a string, but I have also tried range and variant) and nothing works. I definitely have a lack of understanding about objects in vba so that is probably the issue. Also, foundRow confuses me a lot - the vlookup would find the specific cell that I want to copy over into D1, but later it is treated as a row number in .Cells.

Comment: I wrote all that so hopefully it is clear that I am trying! and I am definitely learning from all you have posted - I have been adapting a lot of your code for other uses, so I am very thankful

Comment: Ahhh that is the problem... vlookup does return the *value* from the cell, not the cell's location...  hold on.

Comment: Works great, and I was able to modify the (foundRow, 1) to copy the column from the foundRow that I wanted. So foundRow, 9 copies the value for that row in columm K. Thank you!